# How to Integrate Linkedin in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have problem regarding LinkedIn Authentication in Angular2 my code is.

```
import {Component , OnInit , NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES , Router} from 'angular2/router';

declare var IN : any;

@Component({
  directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  selector : '.main',
  providers : [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl : './app/registration/employee.reg.html'
})

export class EmployeeRegistrationComponent implements OnInit{

 constructor(private zone : NgZone){
    this.zone.run(() => {
        $.proxy(this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad, this);
    });
}

ngOnInit(){
    var linkedIn = document.createElement("script");
    linkedIn.type = "text/javascript";
    linkedIn.src = "http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js";
    linkedIn.innerHTML = "\n"+
        "api_key: **********\n" +
        "authorize: true\n" +
        "onLoad:" + this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad ;
    document.head.appendChild(linkedIn);

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "in/Login";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad = () => {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.OnLinkedInAuth);
}

OnLinkedInAuth = () => {
    IN.API.Profile("me").result(result => this.ShowProfileData);
}

ShowProfileData(profiles) {
    console.log(profiles);
    var member = profiles.values[0];
    var id=member.id;
    var firstName=member.firstName;
    var lastName=member.lastName;
    var photo=member.pictureUrl;
    var headline=member.headline;

    //use information captured above
   }

}
```

Console Throwing Error : `angular2-polyfills.js:1250 Uncaught Error: Could not execute 'function () {'. Please provide a valid function for callback.`

Please Help me out what is wrong I'm doing...

Comment: so is angular allowing you to append the script tag to the dom?

Comment: yes.. As I am using javascript dom functions.. to handle script tags

Comment: @DoubleH Did you ever get this to work? I am having a hard time implementing this and there is little documentation out there on how to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue by inspecting the source code output in the first script tag.

The issue is where you put:

```
"onLoad:" + this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad;
```

It will be output as:

```
onLoad: function () {↵            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", _this.OnLinkedInAuth);↵        }
```

And like it says in the official developper documentation

> Important!
>
> The line breaks between the arguments within the  tags are important since there is no other form of field separator.  If you are using a templating language or code minifier that strips whitespace from your rendered HTML, be aware that you will need to make an exception to preserve the line-breaks within this  tag, otherwise they will not be parsed properly.

Source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk

---

I don't find yet how to resolve the LinkedIn login problem with Angular 2 but I will try again other solutions

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me :

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

   export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit{

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
       window['onLinkedInLoad'] = () => ngZone.run(() => this.onLinkedInLoad());
        window['displayProfiles'] = (profiles) => ngZone.run(() => this.displayProfiles(profiles));
        window['displayProfilesErrors'] = (error) => ngZone.run(() => this.displayProfilesErrors(error));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
              var linkedIn = document.createElement("script");
                        linkedIn.type = "text/javascript";
                        linkedIn.src = "http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js";
                        linkedIn.innerHTML = "\n" +
                           "api_key: ****\n" +
                           "authorize: true\n" +
                           "onLoad: onLinkedInLoad\n"+
                           "scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress";
                        document.head.appendChild(linkedIn);
                        var script = document.createElement("script");
                        script.type = "in/Login";
                        document.body.appendChild(script);
                }

                public onLinkedInLoad() {
                        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.onLinkedInProfile);
                }

                public onLinkedInProfile() {
                            IN.API.Profile("me")
                                .fields("id", "firstName", "lastName", "email-address")
                                .result(this.displayProfiles)
                                .error(this.displayProfilesErrors);
                }
                public displayProfiles(profiles) {
                    console.log(profiles);
                }
                public displayProfilesErrors(error) {
                        console.debug(error);
                }
                //Invoke login window with button
                public liAuth() {
                   IN.User.authorize(function () {
                            console.log('authorize callback');
                   });
                }   
            }
```

Comment: i tried but i got  IN.Event.on(IN undefined ,can you tell me how to fix?

Comment: Check original post : declare var IN: any;
@Component({

Comment: i have already added but same error as well as if i try ur code function is not calling?

Comment: LinkedIn no longer supports the JavaScript SDK 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862429/is-sign-in-with-linkedin-api-cdnhttps-platform-linkedin-com-in-js-broken

Answer (score 0):

Your using javascript dom functions, so you need to change this:

```
"onLoad:" + this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad ;
```

To this:

```
"onLoad: onLinkedInLoad";
```

Now add this to the `<head>` of your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}

</script>
```