# Login with linkedin and get user information in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, linkedin-api, angular-components, angular2-cli

I am new to Angular2, I want to integrate linked login functionality and get the currently singed in user information for my Angular2 project.

I have created App in using linkedin developer account and have **Client ID** and **Client Secret** and tried below code but it gives me error

ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.   at ht……}

I tried both the way for declaring api key using double quotes ( api_key: "81zbsc62i53h5x" and without it ( api_key: 81zbsc62i53h5x) but same error comes.

Included below script in index.html

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 81zbsc62i53h5x
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    scope: r_fullprofile
  </script>
```

code in app.component.ts

```
declare var IN: any;
export class AppComponent {
  onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.onLinkedInAuth);
  }
  public onLinkedInAuth() {
    IN.API.Profile("me")
      .fields("firstName", "lastName")
      .result(this.displayProfiles)
      .error(this.displayProfilesErrors);
  }
  public displayProfiles(profiles) {
    var linkedinmember = profiles.values[0];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(linkedinmember));
    console.log(linkedinmember.firstName + " " + linkedinmember.lastName);
  }
  public displayProfilesErrors(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

app.component.html login button and click

```
 <button (click)="onLinkedInLoad()" class="linkedin-btn">LinkedIn Login</button>
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [LinkedIn API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin#). they have listed down step by step guide on including Sign In button.

Comment: First question is whether you need to access some resources on the back-end. If yes then you need an authorization server that connects with Linkedin, thus the **OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant**. Else if you don't need to connect to your back-end then you can use **OAuth2 Implicit Grant**. The next question is, which grant types does Linkedin support? Implicit grant might not be available. So you might need an Authorization Server. You can implement one or use some of the already existing commercial services like Auth0 [LINK](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/linkedin).

Comment: @MadhuRanjan I have followed the steps from the link provided by you already.I also updated my question to be specific the error I received.Please take a look.

Comment: @omacarena I have updated my question Please take a look and let me know if you have a solutions for this issue.

Comment: @ManojAhuja have you checked if [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325798/you-must-specify-a-valid-javascript-api-domain-as-part-of-this-keys-configurati) solve your issue? - registering the API, domain and maybe waiting for 30min

Comment: @omacarena Yes I followed the steps and register my domain for JavaScript Settings in Linked In.

Comment: @ManojAhuja try removing the `scope: r_fullprofile` because it does not seem to be defined on [their docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#initialize). Next one `onLoad: onLinkedInLoad` is not a valid function. `onLinkedInLoad` is a function defined inside the `AppComponent` class which instance is not available in your global scope.

Comment: @ManojAhuja Now I realized something after reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473508/how-to-integrate-linkedin-in-angular2). Do you use angular-cli for your project? If yes then your index.html might get messed up. Please take a look in your browser at your rendered content and see if the content of your `<script>` looks good and every key-value pair is on separate line.

Comment: @omacarena Yes you are correct I am using angular-cli. I checked my index.html but doesn't seem anything messed.view source of index.html shared here.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/99if7ha9ojjy2zz/Index.png?dl=0

Comment: @ManojAhuja remove the quotes from `api_key` and `onLoad`. You need to expose the function passed to `onLoad` globally.

Comment: @omacarena I removed quotes. Can you elaborate how to expose the function passed to onLoad globally. If possible please give me a code for that..

Comment: @ManojAhuja first you can add a simple dummy function inside `<script>` tags just to check that you are not receiving any errors. Next you can, for example, create a class providing that method as a static method so that it can be called globally. You can provide also a static field that is Observable and the means to subscribe to that observable. Then when you call that static method you can use the observable to notify the subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you try to integrate the linkedin sdk with unregistered domain.
There are 2 things you need to do:
1.Add your domain in the linkedin app panel:
[Linkedin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sSW6.png)

2.Set your host file to test your application when you test the domain.