# How to Retrieve all possible information about a LinkedIn Account using Typescript

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, ionic2, linkedin-api

Hi Currently I am developing Ionic2 framework app with social login, I have added Google plus and facebook button and working fine now I want Implement Linkedin login also I am using Typescript for that and I am not getting how to implement the function I am not getting But I have created app in  linkedin developer console
On linkedin developer console only javascript(Working only on index.html page,I want to add it to another page) and android methods are there could you please tell me how to implement REST Api method

Comment: Can you post some snippets of what you already tried?

Comment: I got only FB and Google plus profile information's I want know how to get Linkedin profile info using REST Api,Angular 2(programming language)

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available on how to use REST on Angular 2. You should make your question more specific or provide code examples of what you already tried.

Comment: I tried this "http://codeexecute.com/linkedin-login-javascript/"  could you please tell how to implement in typescript  without using Oauth 2 and firebase, using javascrpt is work but I want Working on typescript for Ionic 2 framework I am creating a linkedin login button, I want to store some details in mySQL

Answer (score 0):

[Here is straight forward post](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/) about "how to implement REST Api method"

Comment: Do you know how to get LinkedIn profile information using REST api using Angular 2

Comment: I am not able to use Linekdin REST api could you please help me

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?  People can help you out, but they are not going to do the work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502922/login-with-linkedin-and-get-user-information-in-angular2?rq=1     this much I tried

Comment: Thats cool, but what happened when you tried that? If you don't tell us what the specific problem is, we cant help.

Comment: this.IN.Event.on(this.IN, "auth", this.onLinkedInAuth); here I am getting error  Can't read property 'Event' of Undefined  I want to know whats this IN,and Event and what I have to modify to avoid runtime error

Comment: Well, for starters what is `this.IN`, did you define it in your constructor, or did you just copy paste that function? As the error message notes, `this.IN` is undefined and therefore not able to perform as you would expect.  So you need to fix that problem first.

Comment: No that IN is Variable